# Magento: server requirements for a quite big shop to run smoothly

Tags: configuration, magento

I'm working on a quite big magento: it will have 50 different shops (1 magento install, 1 admin to rule them all) for start, this number is expected to raise in the future, and a catalog of more than 1k products. This catalog will be shared by all shops.

I'm concerned about the server requirements I need for this to run smoothly.  So far this is what I've found to get the most of it:
Caching: using magento's cache with APC, MySQL's querys
use FastCGI instead of mod_php
database clustering: I don't think it will be necesary for 1k products, what do you think?
using Zend Server

Are there other thing I can do in order to improve magento's performance? I'd like to know all I need from the beginning so I can find the right server.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure also to use block-level caching for the sites. Beyond this, one of the suggestions that I've seen implemented is to change dynamic blocks (such as blocks that grab product data dynamically) over to statically defined HTML if they don't change often.

Once you've coded a site, tune it using YSlow and Firebug to make sure that as many files as possible are cached, and that the page size is minimized. Minimizing the number of HTTP requests to Apache will increase the capacity of your server.

Finally, enable the flat catalog and flat category functions in Magento. This will force Magento to use fewer joins when retrieving catalog data, so your database load will go down and speed will increase considerably.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: hi Joseph (we meet again :))  it surely helps, thanks.  But my question is more relative to the server configuration: I'm in the process of finding a server and I want to make a list of all I need to pass it to the hosting company.  I see now that the "images sprite" doesn't belong to that list, I'm editing it right now.  Thanks anyway for your suggestion, they are duely noted. CU

Comment: for server config, it depends on the problems you have. for instance, if you are running out of memory, try disabling unneeded modules in apache to make your processes lighter. if your problem is disk access, mount some commonly used directories (images e.g.) in memory. for processor, the optcode cache should help significantly. always nice to see you ;)

Comment: ok, I am sure I'll check back those suggestion when I face the problem. thx again, CU around.

Answer (score 0):

In testing, I noticed amazing improvements using an Amazon instance running ubuntu php-fpm REST and nginx. The only reason I didn't go there with our recent Magento upgrade is the host I'm on still works ok and I really don't want to be sysadmin for my site again.

Also, did you know there is http://magento.stackexchange.com ? :D